# Fit default icons into header button in jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, button, icons

I'm trying to add a menu-style drop down button to the header of a mobile app created via jQuery Mobile, but I cannot find a way to fit the default 'gear' icon to the button. The following is the HTML page.

```
<div data-role="header">    
            <a href="#cfgMenu" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slidedown" data-icon="gear" data-theme="a"></a>

            <div data-role="popup" id="cfgMenu" data-theme="a">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width: 210px;" data-theme="a">
                    <li data-role="divider" data-theme="a">Configura</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lingua</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sci club</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Preferenze</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                <h1>Title</h1>

        </div>
</div>
```

With this HTML the result is the following:    [image: Too little space for icon]

If I add style="height:100%" to the `<a>` the result is the following: [image: Too much space for icon]

What can I do to fit the icon into the image?

---

Just found that adding text everything is OK. But space in the header is limited, so I'd like to avoid this solution

[image: Right space for this solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jQM 1.4 you use button classes instead of the data attributes:

```
<a href="#cfgMenu" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-notext" data-transition="slidedown"  data-theme="a"></a>
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/bxaU5/)**

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. When googling I should pay more attention on the version of jQuery Mobile answer.